# check if date exists BEFORE and AFTER a given date in ONE query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a Mysql/sql query question but allow me to explain the context:
I would like to equip my PHP calendar with a '< PREV' and 'NEXT >' button allowing a user to easily go to the previous or next available month **that has DATABASE ENTRIES AVAILABLE**. If there are no database entries available, I want to disable the button (I never want the system to present an empty calendar).

**Example:**
User has FEB in view.  JAN and MAR do not contain entries but DEC and APR do. The 'NEXT >' button then needs to switch to the April calendar. The '< PREV' button needs to switch to the December calendar.

**So basically I'm looking for a single efficient query that can check if entries exist prior to and after (but not part of) the month in view.**

The table has a field 'logDate' which is of type date 'Y-m-d'.

I started fumbling with the following query to check first whether or not a date exists before and after the given date but I understand that there are some things wrong with this query. For one, if there's an entry in the table for '2013-03-19' my query will spit out a 1 for prev - which of course doesn't indicate if an entry exists for months prior to March.

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(SELECT dayId FROM LogbookDay 
WHERE logDate < '2013-03-20' AND userId = 2), 1, 0) as prev, 
IF( EXISTS(SELECT dayId FROM LogBookDay WHERE logDate > '2013-03-20' 
AND userId = 2), 1, 0) as next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my own query and a pointer from one of the posted answers I have been able to come up with a simple query that checks whether or not entries exist with months prior and after to the month currently in view.

Assuming month in view is March 2013:

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(SELECT dayId FROM LogBookDay 
WHERE logDate < '2012-03-01' AND userId = 1), 1, 0) as prev,
IF( EXISTS(SELECT dayId FROM LogBookDay 
WHERE logDate > CONCAT('2012-03-',LAST_DAY('2003-02-05')) 
AND userId = 1), 1, 0) as next
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify the start date to the beginning and end of the month:
For prev, you modify to the first day of the month, by subtracting 1 less than the current day of the month.  For next, you do the same, then add 1 month:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT dayId FROM LogbookDay WHERE 
    logDate < ADDDDATE('2013-03-20', 1-DAY('2013-03-20')) AND userId = 2
    ORDER BY logDate DESC LIMIT 1
) as PREV,
(SELECT dayId FROM LogBookDay WHERE 
    logDate >= ADDDATE(ADDDDATE('2013-03-20', 1-DAY('2013-03-20')), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND userId = 2
    ORDER BY logDate ASC LIMIT 1
) as NEXT
```

(Or, do this in PHP, as it's likely to result in more readable code.)

Display the link differently depending on if the result is a null or a date.

It might be more elegant if you were pulling a date instead of an ID:

```
    SELECT 
(SELECT MAX(logDate) FROM LogbookDay WHERE 
    logDate < ADDDDATE('2013-03-20', 1-DAY('2013-03-20')) AND userId = 2
) as PREV,
(SELECT MIN(logDate) FROM LogBookDay WHERE 
    logDate >= ADDDATE(ADDDDATE('2013-03-20', 1-DAY('2013-03-20')), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND userId = 2
) as NEXT
```

But that depends on exactly what you're doing with the information you find.  If all you're doing is creating a link to a new month, pulling the nearest date not in the same month should do the trick.

Comment: You'll want to use the mysql date functions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to change the first date to the first of the month, and the last date to the end of the month.  I'm not terribly familiar with those functions (I use mssql most of the time) but it shouldn't be too complex.  Or you can change the dates in PHP before using them in the query.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Basically the first sub select would contain '< 2013-03-01' and the second '> 2013-03-30'. However, your solution does not deal with the fact that these queries return more than one row. I receive a 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' error.

Comment: And I was not notified of this comment for some reason.  To fix that, you'll need "LIMIT 1" and an ORDER BY to make sure you get the right first item.  Updating answer in a moment...

Comment: Dave, thanks for the help. With your suggestion of using the mysql date functions I have been able to construct a much simpler query that does the job. I have posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
if(min(logDate) < '2013-03-20', 1, 0) 'NEXT',
if(max(logDate) > '2013-03-20', 1, 0) 'PAST'
FROM LogbookDay 
WHERE logDate < '2013-03-20' AND logDate > '2013-03-02' 
AND  userId = 2
```